# how to transform a string to an array with # as a delimiter but only the first one?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

(only the first # is a delimiter)

```
50#some message from me to you #1 or #2
```

into

```
array 
(
    [amount] => 50
    [message] => 'some message from me to you #1 or #2'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need regex for such a simple split.
The following will split your string correctly:

`explode('#', $string, 2)`

This will return an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => '50'
    [1] => 'some message from me to you #1 or #2'
)
```

See [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for more details.

If your query does end up getting more complex, then look at [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).